# Java EE Glassfish Virtual Server DNS change http://192.168.16.144:8080/MyAppCorporation-war/ to

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

Hey Guys,
I am developing a application in Java EE using Glassfish V3. The URL of the APP is something like `localhost:8080/MyAppCorporation-war/` and is not very intuitive. I was wondering if this could be changed to something more useful and easier for the users to remember when they try to access the application.  For example, something like myeasyapp. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

In WEB-INF/sun-web.xml put:

```
<sun-web-app>
    <context-root>/this_is_my_funky_url</context-root>
</sun-web-app>
```